# Some packages could not be installed

Tags: ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Windows user here which is taking a daring step into the world of Linux. I am trying to install diamondback under Ubuntu 10.10 OS which is not going my way. I keep getting messages about dependency problem but no information is given about what it needs. So fare I haven't found any logs which might help solving the problem.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ros-diamondback-desktop-full : Depends: ros-diamondback-ros-tutorials (= 0.2.4-s1312444428~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1312444551~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.3-s1312434364~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-ros (= 1.4.9-s1312417704~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-visualization (= 1.4.1-s1312430955~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-vision-opencv (= 1.4.3-s1312425623~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-perception-pcl (= 0.10.0-s1312426677~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-rx (= 1.4.2-s1312429740~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-image-pipeline (= 1.4.2-s1312436357~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo (= 1.2.8-s1312439344~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.0-s1312438884~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-simulator-stage (= 1.2.5-s1312436791~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-image-common (= 1.4.1-s1312425497~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-common-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1312462299~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-ros-comm (= 1.4.7-s1312424612~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-visualization-common (= 1.4.2-s1312429916~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-physics-ode (= 1.4.1-s1312429433~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-driver-common (= 1.2.3-s1312425422~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-executive-smach (= 1.0.2-s1312434262~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-common-msgs (= 1.4.0-s1312424894~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.1-s1312426360~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-robot-model (= 1.4.0-s1312427507~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-visualization-tutorials (= 0.2.2-s1312463900~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-geometry (= 1.4.2-s1312425145~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-documentation (= 1.4.1-s1312464016~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.1-s1312458275~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-laser-pipeline (= 1.2.0-s1312428954~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-common (= 1.4.3-s1312424980~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-diagnostics (= 1.4.0-s1312425329~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: ros-diamondback-navigation (= 1.4.1-s1312429171~maverick) but it is not going to be installed
```

Any help in the right direction would be great.
Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10923/some-packages-could-not-be-installed/) by [miivers](https://answers.ros.org/users/962/miivers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the info. I found a old version of ros for Ubuntu 10.04. I do not know if this made a conflict. I removed everything related to ros in synaptic packet manager and all update entry's related to ros under Software Sources. After this everything went fine when I followed the install guide again.

---

Originally posted by [miivers](https://answers.ros.org/users/962/miivers/) with karma: 26 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0